# Word VBA Access Active X Control on Document Using a Variable

Tags: variables, ms-word

I am totally stuck and would appreciate any help.

I have Word document with a large number of active x controls on it. I would like to be able to double click on any label and change the caption. The caption is to be entered using an input box. Rather than have masses of duplicate code, I would like to store the label name in a variable and pass it to a function to do the change.

The problem I am encountering is finding a way to store and use the control name as a variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have exhausted my google trawling.

I have tried the "me." and "Controls." both failed.

Comment: You are much more likely to get responses if you edit your answer to include code that does at least some of what you describe.

FWIW whenever anyone mentions any Word document programming problem that involves activeX controls, my first question is "are you dealing with a legacy support problem?", i.e. could you solve the problem by ditching the decades-old ActiveX controls and using something more modern?"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.